# Laravel OrWhereNull giving wrong results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this long query builder where I am basically searching a table and then filter the results based on the passed query strings:

```
$projects = Listing::query()
            ->when(request('q'), function($builder) {
                $builder->searchQuery(request('q'));
            })
            ->when(request('tags'), function($builder) {
                $tags = request('tags');

                $builder->whereHas('tags', function($builder) use ($tags) {
                    $builder->whereIn('name', $tags);
                });
            })
            ->when(request('categories'), function($builder) {
                $categories = request('categories');

                $builder->whereHas('categories', function($builder) use ($categories) {
                    $builder->whereIn('name', $categories);
                });
            })
            ->when(request('countries'), function($builder) {
                $countries = request('countries');

                $builder->when(count($countries),function ($builder) use ($countries) {
                    $builder->whereHas('location', function($builder) use ($countries) {
                        $builder->where( function($builder) use ($countries) {
                            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                                $builder->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $country . '%');
                                //$builder->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $country . '%');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }); 
            })
            ->when(request('opensource'), function($builder) {
                $builder->where('open_source', request('opensource'));
            })
            ->when(request('types'), function($builder) {
                $types = request('types');
                if (in_array("Other", $types)) {
                    $key = array_search("Other", $types);
                    $types[$key] = NULL;

                    $builder->whereIn('type', $types)->orWhereNull('type');
                } else {
                    $builder->whereIn('type', $types);   
                }
            })
            ->when(request('organizationtypes'), function($builder) {
                $organizationtypes = request('organizationtypes');
                if (in_array("Other", $organizationtypes)) {
                    $key = array_search("Other", $organizationtypes);
                    $organizationtypes[$key] = NULL;

                    $builder->whereIn('organization_type', $organizationtypes)->orWhereNull('organization_type');
                } else {
                    $builder->whereIn('organization_type', $organizationtypes);   
                }
            })
            ->when(request('status'), function($builder) {
                $status = request('status');
                if ($status == "Show active projects only") {
                    $builder->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A']);
                } else {
                    $builder = $builder;
                }
            })
            ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(50);
```

The query works well, however, my issue is with this part:

```
$status = request('status');
if ($status == "Show active projects only") {
     $builder->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A']);
} else {
     $builder = $builder;
}
```

I would like if $status == "Show active projects only", then to show projects whose status is "Active", "N/A" and null. However when I modify the if part to:

```
$builder->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A'])->orWhereNull('status');
```

I get wrong results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add that part into its own closure, just like you have for the countries. That will turn the query from "where this and this and this and this or this" to "this and this and this and (this or this)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enclose the `whereIn()` and the `orWhereNull()` in another where.
I'm quesing the `orWhereNull()` expands wider than the limitation within the status.

```
->when(request('status'), function($builder) {
    $status = request('status');
    if ($status == "Show active projects only") {
        $builder->where(function($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A'])
                         ->orWhereNull('status');
        });
    }
    // This doesn't do anything, so this can be removed
    // else {
    //   $builder = $builder;
    // }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think the easiest answer is just to add `null` to your array.

```php
$builder->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A', null]);
```

---

That said (and of course it's a matter of opinion), you could make your code much more readable by use of arrow functions and some other consolidation/optimization. Note my use of `request()->filled()` as opposed to just checking if `request('key')` is truthy. If the submitted value is "0" it would return false in your existing code.

```php
$projects = Listing::query()
    ->when(
        request()->filled('q'),
        fn ($q) => $q->searchQuery(request('q'))
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('tags'),
        fn ($q) => $q->whereHas(
            'tags',
            fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('name', request('tags'))
        )
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('categories'),
        fn ($q) => $q->whereHas(
            'categories',
            fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('name', request('categories'))
        )
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('countries'),
        fn ($q) => $q->whereHas(
            'location',
            function ($q) {
                foreach(request('countries') as $country) {
                    $q->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $country . '%');
                }
            })
        )
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('opensource'),
        fn ($q) => $q->where('open_source', request('opensource'));
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('types'),
        function ($q) {
            $types = array_map(
                fn ($v) => $v === "Other" ? null : $v,
                request('types')
            );
            $q->whereIn('type', $types);
        }
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('organizationtypes'),
        function ($q) {
            $types = array_map(
                fn ($v) => $v === "Other" ? null : $v,
                request('organizationtypes')
            );
            $q->whereIn('organization_type', $types);
        }
    )
    ->when(
        request()->filled('status'),
        fn ($q) => $q->when(
            $status === "Show active projects only",
            fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('status', ['Active', 'N/A', null])
        )
    )
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(50);
```